# carriage lines and splitting cell values in pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

my data is in a pandas DataFrame with each row, structured like this:

```
> df={'date1': '0 \r Created February 21, 2015', 'amt': '$50,815 raised by 498 donors'}
```

I want it to look like this

```
>df={'month': 'February', 'day': 21, 'year': '2015, 'cur': '$', 'raised': '50815', 'num_donor': '498'}
```

`df.date1`, many of my cells contain carriage returns, sometimes several in a row (at the beginning and end of strings). Is there any way to remove them from the entire DataFrame?

In some cases, this works:

```
> df['date1'] = df['date1'].map(lambda x: str(x).lstrip('\r Created').rstrip('...'))
```

but this does not always work (code from diff columns). for example, none of the following will remove \r or ','

```
> df['raised2'][0] = ,50,815,\r 

> df['raised2'] = df['raised2'].map(lambda x: str(x).lstrip('\r').rstrip('\r'))

> rm_carriage = lambda x: re.findall("^/\r*(.*?)/\r*$", str(x))

> df.applymap(carriage_function)
```

This gets me the Month but the same logic will not get my the day or year

```
> df['month'] = df['date1'].map(lambda x: x.split()[0])

> df['day'] = df['date1'].map(lambda x: x.split()[1])   #IndexError
```

Answer (score 0):

Depends on exact data, but for your example this should work

```
df['date1_splitted'] = df.date1.str.replace('\r|,', ' ').apply(lambda x: filter(None, x.split(' ')))
df['year'] = df.date1_splitted.apply(lambda x: x[2])
df['day'] = df.date1_splitted.apply(lambda x: x[1])
df['month'] = df.date1_splitted.apply(lambda x: x[0])
df['amt_splitted'] = df.amt.str.replace('\r|,', '').apply(lambda x: x.split(' '))
df['cur'] = df.amt_splitted.apply(lambda x: x[0][0])
df['raised'] = df.amt_splitted.apply(lambda x: x[0][1:])
df['num_donors'] = df.amt_splitted.apply(lambda x: x[-2])
```